# Image doesn't fit table cell

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to build a page that has a design like the one in the picture below:

[image]

So in the place where **img**  word is shown, there is an image that should fit that area. 
And the text below  should be no higher than the image on the left side.

I tried to build it with a table like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
table { max-width: 100%; }
table, th, td { border-collapse: collapse;}
td img { width: 100%; max-width: 100%; height: auto;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing='0' nowrap valign="baseline" border="0" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>    
            <td rowspan="3" colspan="3"><img src="http://www.si-faosmanlisabunlari.com/wp-content/uploads/not_included.jpg"/></td>  
            <td><img src="http://www.fxebay.de/img/gallery/fullsize/400x600.gif" /></td>    
            <td><img src="http://www.fxebay.de/img/gallery/fullsize/400x600.gif" /></td>    
            <td><img src="http://www.fxebay.de/img/gallery/fullsize/400x600.gif" /></td>    
            <td><img src="http://www.fxebay.de/img/gallery/fullsize/400x600.gif" /></td>    
            <td><img src="http://www.fxebay.de/img/gallery/fullsize/400x600.gif" /></td>    
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="http://www.fxebay.de/img/gallery/fullsize/400x600.gif" /></td>    
            <td><img src="http://www.fxebay.de/img/gallery/fullsize/400x600.gif" /></td>    
            <td><img src="http://www.fxebay.de/img/gallery/fullsize/400x600.gif" /></td>    
            <td><img src="http://www.fxebay.de/img/gallery/fullsize/400x600.gif" /></td>    
            <td><img src="http://www.fxebay.de/img/gallery/fullsize/400x600.gif" /></td>    
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <h3>Collezione UOMO FALLWINTER 14/15</h3>
                Non rinuncia all’eleganza l’uomo DUNO, ma lo fa consapevole d’indossare un brand che è la nuova origine del vestire giovane. La linea uomo di DUNO per questa stagione è caratterizzata da capispalla, piumini e giacconi dallo stile inconfondibile. Comodi e dalla grande portabilità in ogni contesto, dall’evento speciale ai tour outdoor, i capi DUNO sono un alleato raffinato e solido.
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

But the image in the left doesn't expand  to fit all the table cell ...

I don't know if I could achieve this using divs or how.

Comment: Your issue lies in the size of your image that is called "not-included.jpg". If you set height to auto, it is proportionate to the width. So the way you had the columns set up, it would not fill vertically.

Comment: Just FYI, your left cell's `colspan="3"` is useless, since it takes all three rows, it's not spanning any column. You can remove it.

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to use a background image instead:

```
background:url('not_included.jpg') center no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
width:300px;
```

Answer (score 0):

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/30pvsacm/)

I took the image out of the table and instead added it as a background image using CSS. This gives you access to background manipulation options, such as `background-size`.

Table cell:

```
<td rowspan="3" colspan="3" class='cellWithBG'>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>               
</td>
```

CSS:

```
.cellWithBG { 
      background-image:url('http://www.si-faosmanlisabunlari.com/wp-content/uploads/not_included.jpg'); 
      background-size:cover; 
      background-repeat: no-repeat; 
      min-width:200px;
}
```

The `min-width` of the table cell in question depends on your image and how you want it to look. Personally I would do this with divs instead of a table, but I'm assuming your project requires a table.